# Julia vector question: generating sequential intergers and the same values

Tags: vector, julia

I have a beginner Julia question regarding generating two types of vectors:

1. How to I generate a vector consisting out of n of the same elements, without having to type it out manually? For example, how do I generate a vector v consisting out of 7 times the number 5, thus `v = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5]`.
2. How do I generate a vector with n sequential integers starting at integer x, again without having to type it out manually? For example how do I generate a vector z with 10 sequential integers starting at 1, thus `z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
julia> v = fill(5, 7); 

julia> @show v;
v = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

julia> z = collect(1:10);

julia> @show z;
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Note that in the second case, often you can operate on the range `1:10` directly without having to do a `collect` on it (`z = 1:10`). `1:10` is a `Range` type, that works by saving just the starting and ending points, without allocating memory for all 10 values. `collect` converts that into a full `Vector`, which allocates memory for each element.

Comment: `1:10` is a Range, but it is also an `AbstractVector`, meaning that almost every way it is equal to a `Vector`, except it is immutable, and it is much faster and more lightweight. I would emphasize that one should _almost never_ `collect` a range (or anything else.)

Answer (score 0):

1. To generate the example: `v = repeat([5],7])`
2. To generate the example: `z = [1:10;]`

Comment: These are much less idiomatic than what Sundar suggests. (And 1. unnecessarily allocates.)